# how to use this condition in a loop ($1==col2[$1])&& ($2>=col2[$2])&& ($3<=col2[$3]) to compare two files first three column

Tags: r, awk, sed

I have two set of genomic coordinates. the problem is file1  ranges are small, when i compare with file2, it can have multiple overlaps. so i want to pick as close as possible. The problem is file1's first row (assume you have many row) can goes file2's first and second row. How to use this condition in a loop  ($1==col2[$1])&& ($2>=col2[$2])&& ($3<=col2[$3]) like this. so that i can take only file2's second row.

file_2

```
1   1400158 1400608 +   ENSE00003459370 
1   1400158 1400544 +   ENSE00003542737
1   2515258 2515401 -   ENSE00001912971
1   11025110    11025203    +   ENSE00003713710
1   13892792    13893756    +   ENSE00003793480
1   15328277    15328429    +   ENSE00003788031
1   15329346    15329541    +   ENSE00003484579
1   15247280    15247395    +   ENSE00002149103
```

I have file1

```
1   1400473 1400544 +
```

Desired output is

```
1   1400158 1400544 +   ENSE00003542737
```

I tried with this

```
awk 'NR==FNR { id[$1]=$1; id1[$2]=$2; id2[$3]=$3; next } ($1 == id && $2 >= id1 && $3 <= id2) { print $0"\t"id[$1]"\t"id1[$2]"\t"id2[$3]}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

But i'm not getting the output. I don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: does `1 1400473 1400544 +` need to match in its entirety or `1400473 1400544` is enough?

Comment: please update the question to provide an explanation on which columns you are comparing, making sure to describe what you mean by 'overlap' (and which column(s) can 'overlap')

Comment: it would also help to know if multilpe rows from `file2` can 'match' a single row from `file1` and if so then update the question to show an example; also, what should be output if a row from `file1` does not have a 'match' in `file2`? (also provide an example)

Comment: Do you want to consider strandedness, only matching opposite or same strands?

Comment: Am I understanding properly: columns 2 and 3 give span position starts and stops and you wish to match the span in file2 which includes the greatest proportion of file1's current span, choosing the shortest from file2 if more than one of file2's spans contains the entire sequence (and otherwise taking the longest enclosed span regardless of file2 span size)?

Comment: That's not a problem if the file1 has more than one  file2's spans, i can take both of them.

Comment: `"col1[$2]=$2; col1[$3]=$3; next}"`   is not making sense to me  especially since you call it with  `col1[$5]` an ENS-id but populated it with integer genomic locations.

Comment: Sorry, it's just a try. I know something is wrong but not sure where and why

Comment: If you describe your problems in terms of values in rows and columns rather than `i have two set of genomic coordinates...` then people who aren't familiar with whatever domain you work in, but may be experts in the tools you want to use, will also be able to help you.

Comment: sounds like you want to use bedtools

Answer (score 0):

Lots of missing info/confusion here, for example the size, in rows, of each file may matter allot, also what you explicitly ask for is not likely what you actually need as it does nothing to include any reference to file1 that indicates why a result from file2 is kept.

but guessing at something that could be close to what you are after ...

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f 


NR==FNR && !/^$/{                    # collect all file1 (no ens_id)
    n = NR;
    ch[n] = $1;
    lo[n] = $2;
    hi[n] = $3;
    # sense[n] = $4;                # could check direction as well

} 

NR!=FNR && !/^$/ {                  # each item file2
    i=last_hit;
    while(i++ < n){                 # each item in file1
                                    #  *** assume lo strictly before hi
                    

        if(($1 != ch[i]) || ($2 > hi[i]) || ($3<lo[i]) ){   # no chance
                last_hit = i-1;                             # retry with next                       
                next
        }
        else {                                              # plausible 
            if( ($2<=lo[i]) && ($3>=hi[i]) ){               # contained?
                print;                                      # hit
                last_hit = i-1;                             # in case dup hits
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Lots to go wrong but basically you want to know;
if an interval you have (file1) is contained in a named interval from file2, presumably because you want to know the reference name for your interval from file1.

The important part is less what you choose to print when a hit is found,
you can fix that
and more how to move through the first file repeatedly as you consider each row in the second file.

The `last_hit` is  bit of (premature) optimization that depends on the intervals being  ordered  within their files, it should allow less of file1 to be revisited as you progress through file2.